# log4net 2 vs 1.2.11 from nuget

Tags: .net, reference, log4net, nuget

I have dependencies problems with `log4net 1.2.11` vs `2.0.0` even though eventually they are the same, [according to the nuget package page](http://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/2.0.0).

[image: dependency graph]

All of the projects have `log4net 2.0.0` package in their `packages.config` and the same reference code in the `csproj` file, but for some reason `ndepend` and referencing process after compilation keep failing and claiming versions mismatch;

`<Reference Include="log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\log4net.2.0.0\lib\net40-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>`

Projects `2 and 3` are 3rd party libraries, but `1 and 4` are under my control and I can't understand what should I do to make them also thinking they are bound to `v2.0.0` rather then `1.2.11`.

Thanks.

Comment: you would need to update csproj 1 & 4 to change reference : <Reference Include="log4net, Version=2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">

Comment: Thanks cpo, I did try to do that, but the result for some reason was the same, besides, project 2 and 3 clearly state `Version=1.2.11.0` and thus I don't understand where it takes v2 from.   

If I open the assembly that is downloaded in separate builds with hex editor they all show 1.2.11. Where is the number 2.0.0 is coming from...

Comment: v2.0.0 is the NuGet package version not the log4net assembly version in the NuGet package is 1.2.11.0. So your project references look OK. I would check all the assembly versions of log4net to see what they are and add binding redirects if they are different.

Comment: That's exactly the issue Matt, they all look the same and has same md5 signatures if i compile each project separately and let it download it's own version of nuget.